# differentiating multiple submit button using PropertiesMethodNameResolver

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, form-submit

I have a form with different submit buttons in Spring MVC application which is in **xml**. I differentiated using **ParameterMethodNameResolver** like

```
<bean id="mnr" class="pkg.ParameterMethodNameResolver">
   <property name="paramName" value="opt"/>
</bean>
```

But the problem here is, Method names are tightly bounded to button captions. So any modification in UI will affect java application. So I just want to use **PropertiesMethodNameResolver**.I used like

```
   <bean id="mnr" class="pkg.PropertiesMethodNameResolver">
      <property name="mappings">
        <props>
          <prop key="user.htm?opt=save">register</prop>
          <prop key="user.htm?opt=delete">remove</prop>
        </props>
       </property>
    </bean>
```

But it is not recognizing that url with params.It is **expecting direct match** url.So how can i solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`PropertiesMethodNameResolver` supports path matching using `AntPathMatcher`. you can use pattern to map URL like this :

```
<prop key="/**/user.htm?opt=save">register</prop>
will map to /api/user.html?opt=save or /api/v1/user.html?opt=save
```

you can check more details about pattern matcher [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html)